# Need help creating script to take usernames and run it through AD, and output address

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to create a script to help me search 2000+ usernames on AD, and output their Address information. I have a list of usernames on a excel sheet. Any suggestions where to start? Thanks

Comment: Lot of information is available over the internet. Like this one https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx

Comment: *"Any suggestions where to start?"* Your preferred search engine. There must be a gazillion examples out there. Please show some effort.

Comment: "Anny suggestions where to start?" [is not a real question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a commonly requested issue. But here is some example code assuming that you have RSAT installed for the Active Directory cmdlets:

```
$ImportedCSV = Import-CSV C:\Input.csv
$ADUsers = Get-ADUser -filter * -properties StreetAddress | select SamAccountName,StreetAddress
$Output = Foreach ($Entry in $ImportedCsv) {
    Foreach ($user in $ADUsers) {
        if ($user.SamAccountName -eq $entry.Username) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Username = $user.SamAccountName
                Address = $entry.StreetAddress
            }
        }
    }
}
$Output | Export-CSV C:\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am an amateur in this, so sorry for the dumb questions, However, how do I create a .csv file, and what should be inside of it? thanks

Comment: In excel you would save in the CSV format. In my example, the first row will need to be `Username` with the usernames in the same column.

Comment: okay, I will try that. Thank you so much, adjusted it a little bit, and ran the script and it's been hanging for 5 min or so, is that okay ?

Comment: Short answer, it depends on several factors, mostly size of the spreadsheet/environment. `Get-ADUser -filter *` returns every user object in Active Directory. Then you are looping through all of the returned objects once for every entry in your spreadsheet. If you have a  large directory, then 5 minutes+ is definitely possible.